# How should I print runtime information to stdout when assigning python output to a variable in bash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, stdout, stderr

I am calling a Python3 program from a bash script. The program takes command line arguments that include a `datetime` (eg '20151211203000') which is used to return the source URLs of images as a python list, then print them to a terminal in a for-loop using `print()`. The bash script reads a text file with rows of `datetime` strings, gets the list of URLs from the python program, then downloads each of the images in the list in turn.

The python program also contains other print statements that are used for error exceptions. I'm relatively new to scripting in bash and working between it and python scripts - I've set the bash script to `grep` the python output for a URL as validation for the output. This worked fine until I improved the program so that it navigates to the webpage containing the images for the following day, if they're within the specified timespan, and used further `print()` statements for debugging. The output of the informative debugging strings that aren't caught up in exceptions is then appended to the list of strings that are used with `wget` and returns unwanted files from random URLs.

This now works, as I've used the keyword argument `file` in the python3 print statements to specify `sys.stderr` as the output. Below are examples from the python program and bash script that should highlight my previous efforts and any gaps in my knowledge with regards to the right way of going about this.

From my bash script:

```sh
...
urls=(`python3 get_keos_url.py $date -dt $2 -i $3`)
...
# Check output to ensure python3 program didn't fall into exception, have URL as first output otherwise
if echo "${urls[0]}" | grep -q "http"; then

    ...

#   Download URLs, now iterating over each array element
    for u in ${urls[@]}; do
        wget --no-verbose "${u}" -P $dir$d &&
        echo "Download complete."
    done
else
#   Echo excepted error message to stdout
    echo ${urls[@]}
fi
```

and from the python3 program:

```py
import mechanicalsoup as ms
import sys
import argparse

def find_keos(obs_datetime, dt=1.5,
              site="SIF"):
    url="http://www.exampleurl-"+site+".com"
    browser = ms.StatefulBrowser()
    browser.open(url)

    ...

    try:
        browser.follow_link(browser.find_link(link_text=day_text))
    except ms.LinkNotFoundError:
        # Example of print from exception - to stdout
        print("No keograms are available for {}.\n\n".\
              format(obs_datetime.strftime(r"%d-%m-%Y")))

        # Used this to ensure message printed to terminal
        sys.stdout.flush()

        return None

    ...

    if (t_end.day > obs_datetime.day) or\
           (t_end.month > obs_datetime.month) or\
               (t_end.year > obs_datetime.year):

        # Example of "informative" print, included for debugging but kept to provide runtime info.
        # This causes a bug - grep catches the URL that's appended to the string below in the first entry
        print("Looking in next day-URL:{}\n".format(browser.get_url()))

        # Included file=sys.stderr as fix
        print("Looking in next day-URL:{}\n".format(browser.get_url()),
              file=sys.stderr)

    ...
    return image_urls

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    keos = find_keos(date, dt=args.dt, site=args.instrument)
    ...
    if keos:
        for k in keos:
            print(k)
```

Note that the exception printouts were written simultaneously with the bash script, while the example of the debugging print was written sometime after to improve the program.

Previously, for cases where the debugging printout is not executed, my bash script implementation worked fine. After editing the code and now seeing cases where the debugging printout is executed, the implementation fails as the stdout is somehow merged with the returned URLs. I used `file=sys.stderr` to get around this, and it now works.

This may be a roundabout way to ask, but my primary question is:

*How should print statements be sent to standard output if they contain strings that are not wanted in output to bash?*

I know the adage "no news is good news" is often followed for computer programs, and sending output that isn't used but that also isn't an error to `stderr` seems odd.

Is there another version of the `stdout` stream that print statements can be sent to from python? Or is there a better way to assign program output to variables in bash scripts?

Comment: Why not going all the way with python?

Comment: You could send your output to a log file which is pretty typical, but sending to stderr doesn't really seem odd to me in this case

Comment: Plenty of things that are not errors are sent to `stderr`, for example the output from `set -x` and `set -v`.

Comment: @balderman - the bash script also creates directories for each of the dates to store each set of images, as well as text files that contain the filepaths of each image for convenience later. I learnt of Python's `subprocess` module as I was writing this code and started to implement it with `subprocess.run()`, but thought the bash scripting would be easier for file creation with variable names etc given that subprocesses are independent. Maybe there was something I was missing and it may have been easier with Python, but I was keen to learn more bash scripting.

Comment: It is quite easy to make folders and files using  python. I would drop the bash and use python only. As a bonus you will get code that will run on Windows as well

Comment: @balderman - does the independence of subprocesses imply that the full path has to be given for every command? I'm assuming that `subprocess.run()` is the main method I'd need to implement this solely in Python, but your suggestion is a good one. I'll probably follow that advice in the future.

Comment: The full path does not have to be given, provided the directory name the program resides in is in the `PATH` environment variable, and you have relevant permissions.  Relative paths (like `./stuff`) can also be given but are best avoided for portability.

Comment: There are several reasons for using one language, python, rather than  `bash`.  One is that `bash` is particularly *inefficient*. For example, `mkdir` runs in its own separate process, as do the majority of "commands".  From python `os.mkdir` there is a thin python layer not a new child process, and then it is a direct kernel call via C (assuming you are using the C implementation of python) - it is the difference between `man 1 mkdir` and `man 2 mkdir`.